# Get error for sum after casting as date sql

Tags: mysql, sql, time, casting

Get an error every time I try to sum after casting timestamp as date (ERROR: function sum(date) does not exist)

```
sum(CAST(timestamp AS DATE))
```

Comment: Why are you summing a date?  What would the result of two dates added together be?  That's why you're getting an error.  What you're attempting to do makes no sense.

Comment: I want to count how many had the same date so if the date 2019-12-31 is repeated 4 times I want it to show me 4

Comment: then COUNT, don't SUM

Comment: @RioCaribe8565 you need  `count`  followed by `group by` not `SUM`